# Docker container runs and quits immediately

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have been trying to make a dockerfile that creates a webserver which can server html and php pages.

I require the images to be built which when it is run it executes a shell script at start up once.

I have been trying to do this with ENTRYPOINT but what I am finding is that the container runs but then immediately exits.

I require this to be coded in the dockerfile as the image is run direct from GCP on a VM using the Container-Optimized OS where it runs the docker image at startup of the VM (so I do not have the option to use docker run -c).

This is my current attempt.

```
FROM php:7.2-apache
COPY / /var/www/html/
EXPOSE 80

ADD start_container.sh /usr/bin/start_container
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/start_container

ENTRYPOINT ["start_container"]
```

I have also tried this with

```
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-php-entrypoint && start_container"]; sleep infinity
```

and

```
CMD ["docker-php-entrypoint"]
```

At the moment the bash script is just creating a html file.

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

cat>/var/www/html/indextest.html
```

Comment: Does it quit, or does it begin running? Do `docker ps` to see information on running containers, and `docker ps -a` to see all your containers. By the looks for it, you do not have a `bash` entry point, so the container won't run in your terminal the way I expect you expect it will.

Comment: Seems to me like your Dockerfile has no purpose. What happens if you change the ADD line to: `ADD start_container.sh /usr/bin/start_container.sh`, RUN to: `RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/start_container.sh` and replace ENTRYPOINT with CMD like: `CMD bash /usr/bin/start_container.sh`

Comment: Also how are you running the docker image?

Comment: @daudnadeem I have made the changes but it still returns a status of Exited (0) 10 seconds ago. the image is run on GCP in a Container-Optmised OS which takes the image and runs it at startup of the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I faces was because the apache web server would start up from the script then I would run a command in script which would complete then close the container off.

The solution was to write error logging into the script and keep the apache service running by adding a wait on service which keeps the service alive forever:  wait "$START_WS_PID" this keeps the last service PID running.

```
# SIGTERM-handler
term_handler() {
  exit 143; # 128 + 15 -- SIGTERM
}
# setup handlers
trap 'term_handler' SIGTERM


function exportBoolean {
    if [ "${!1}" = "**Boolean**" ]; then
            export ${1}=''
    else 
            export ${1}='Yes.'
    fi
}


# Start Job Server
if [ $LOG_LEVEL == 'debug' ]; then
    /usr/sbin/apachectl -DFOREGROUND -k start -e debug &
    START_WS_PID="$!"
else
    &>/dev/null /usr/sbin/apachectl -DFOREGROUND -k start &
    START_WS_PID="$!"
    echo $!
fi
echo $START_WS_PID
**Do something on the command line**
wait "$START_WS_PID"
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to override the `CMD` or `entrypoint` as the [base image start appache](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/af0a051a02c4f3245752e118e9a0da8c8e291107/7.2/buster/apache/Dockerfile) from the `CMD`, that is why your container dies as soon as it executes your bash script that just creates index.html. the life of container is the life of entrypoint so entrypoint should run a long-running process that keep them running.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "hello world" > /var/www/html/indextest.html
```

In the above case, the container will exit once it creates the `index.html`.

Workaround to your case

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "hello" > /var/www/html/index.html
exec apache2-foreground
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.2-apache
EXPOSE 80
ADD start_container.sh /usr/bin/start_container
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/start_container
ENTRYPOINT ["start_container"]
```

then

```
docker build -t test . && docker run -dit -p 8090:80 --rm abc && sleep 2 &&  curl localhost:8090
```

You will see hello world from container in terminal.

but better to put `index.html` to docker build time and then you do not need to override the entrypoint or CMD.

```
FROM php:7.2-apache
RUN echo "hello world" > /var/www/html/index.html
EXPOSE 80
```

Comment: okay this is getting me very very close to working perfectly for me. so unfortunately when I run my script and then exec apache2-foreground I get an error in the logs saying                                                                                                 (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs                           Do you know what might be causing this ?

Comment: you should not run again in `docker exec ` as the process is already running. that is why it showing port is already occupied.

Answer (score 0):

If by "runs" you mean a `bash` prompt, you can do the following:

```sh
docker build -t [NAME]
docker run -it [NAME] /bin/bash
```

This will prompt you with the containers `bash`. To check if the container was built, you can do `docker ps -a`.

Comment: I think he means that when he actually runs the image, it doesn't stay up as a container. And I'm assuming it's because of "ENTRYPOINT"

Comment: No I need it to run the bash script start_container.sh when the container is run, at the moment when I do docker run -d -p 8080:80 --name myapp aa0d524b8c06 and then do docker ps the image isn't running it is shown under docker ps -a so it has run and exited immediately

Comment: Is `start_container` a `.sh` file? You didn't seem to specify what is/was. If so, your issue is indeed `ENTRYPOINT` and the way you are calling the `start_container.sh` file.

Comment: @daudnadeem thank you for the clarification -- makes complete sense.

Comment: so I very much maybe wrong but I though that using ADD start_container.sh /usr/bin/start_container would put the .sh script into a folder called start_container, the run  chmod is permissions
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/start_container
then the entrypoint runs the content of the given folder when the image is run.
ENTRYPOINT ["start_container"]

Comment: So `ADD` copies over directories/files, and you cannot intertwine both. Either you do `ADD dir/ machine/` or you do `ADD dir/file.sh machine/file.sh`. `RUN` looks good, but you are missing the `.sh` extension:  `RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/start_container.sh`. The `ENTRYPOINT` is wrong, as you need to call with the appropriate tool: `ENTRYPOINT ["bin/bash/", "start_container.sh"]`